# Does javascript have access to my bookmarks and history?

Tags: firefox, security, browser, javascript, privacy

I'm using RefControl addon for firefox, to avoid sending the referer in the headers.

But now I'm wondering if the previous page or even my full history can be viewed by websites with javascript.

And what about bookmarks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing `document.referrer` via JavaScript while using RefControl gives the same modified value as in the HTTP header. You can verify this by running `alert(document.referrer)` in the Web Console with RefControl enabled (and configured) and then with RefControl disabled.

There has never been an official way to retrieve the addresses further down in the history. There are ways to detect if certain addresses have been visited in the past by testing if the browser applies a CSS rule for a `:visited` pseudo-class, but modern browsers have countermeasures against this.

Bookmarks are not accessible for JavaScript running in a normal web page, so there should be no way to get any information.

So the answer is no.